# CSS: Overlapping borders

Tags: css

I just stumbled on a problem where the shared border between a menu bar and the main content box does not go on properly (as the content box is too small)

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF2QX.jpg

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/gh55e/2/

So I was wondering if there was a way to fix the border. Maybe by giving them both one and making it overlap? Just have no idea how to do this as margin -x doesn't work.

Comment: Post some CSS that you are using and we can suggest improvements.

Comment: Good point, here is a demo of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gh55e/2/

Comment: I'm guessing you want either column could be the longer one: so in this case, the main content box is too small, but it may be the opposite and the menu bar will be the smaller one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Give the right element a border all around, then use the margin-top and margin-left properties in the negatives to make them overlap. Here's an updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh55e/4/

CSS:

```
#right {
    width: 85px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: -54px;
}
​
```

Comment: Negative margin is generally, and almost always, not advised.

Answer (score 1):

For later visitors, this is the CSS that eventually fixed it.

```
#right {
    width: 385px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

You basically make a margin of 10px and move it back for 10 px

Comment: It looks like Jackson Gariety's answer lead you in the right direction, and you should give him credit for the answer.